# Upper table visibility in selects with subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT b.user_id FROM users b where b.ratings_count !=      
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
      ( SELECT wi.id FROM winelist_items wi
        JOIN wine_rated wr
        ON rate_user_id = b.user_id
        AND rate_vintage_id = wi.vintage_id
        AND wi.winelist_id = (SELECT id FROM winelist w
        WHERE w.user_id = b.user_id LIMIT 1 )
        AND wi.vintage_id !=0
      )t 
    ) limit 10;
```

It has to select all the user_id from users that have different ratings_count in the column from the one being calculated 
by sql. But the problem is that I'm receiving error message 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'b.user_id' in 'on clause' '. What I'm 
doing wrong? Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: "SELECT id FROM winelist w WHERE w.user_id = b.user_id LIMIT 1" What do you think this does!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
 SELECT b.user_id,
     (SELECT count(wi.id)
          FROM wine_rated wr
          JOIN winelist_items wi ON wr.rate_vintage_id = wi.vintage_id
          WHERE wr.rate_user_id = b.user_id  
          AND wi.winelist_id =
              (SELECT id
               FROM winelist w
               WHERE w.user_id = wi.rate_user_id LIMIT 1)
          AND wi.vintage_id !=0 ) AS CNT
FROM users b
GROUP BY b.user_id HAVING b.ratings_count !=CNT LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'b.user_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: please try again with latest changed sql.

Comment: can u please try it again?

Comment: Smth wrong again: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'b.ratings_count' in 'having clause'. There are column ratings_count in users table

Comment: can u please tell me  structure of users table?

Comment: i think there is no column named ratings_count in users table.

Comment: Thank you very much seem to be working I just added b.ratings_count in upper select